# Eloquent max value of child's child

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
auctions [id, winner_user_id, title]
bids [id, auction_id, amount, user_id]
users [id, name]
```

relations

```
Auction
...
public function winningBidder(){
   return $this->belongsTo('User', 'winner_user_id', 'id');
}
public function bids(){
   return $this->hasMany('Bid');
}
```

```
User
...
public function bids(){
   return $this->hasMany('Bid');
}
```

```
Bid
...
public function auction(){
   return $this->belongsTo('Auction');
}
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

What i am trying to do is the highest bid for the winner

```
eager load
$auctions = Auction::with('winningBidder.bids')->get();
```

loads all bids instead of bids of that auction and adding max(amount) to about will give max of all

is it possible to get highest bid of winning user for each auction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to eager load the `winningBidders` and the `winningBid` with each auction you could do the following:

In your `Auction` model add a new `one-to-one` relationship for the highest / winning bid:

```
public function winningBid()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Bid')->max('amount');
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$auctions = Auction::with(['winningBidder', 'winningBid'])->get();
```

Comment: getting error -> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

Comment: @Creatix Yes my mistake, you have to use an array when eager loading multiple relationships, as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships). I edited the answer.